# strip <script> tags from a text using php + security problems?

Tags: php

I want to use php in order to strip only the  tags. I have other tags like images and links. After some search I did I found strip tags function in php but it seems to strip all tags and that is not going to work in my case. By striping  tags from text is that enough to prevent any security problems ?

Comment: Why to strip them instead of using `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: If you want to allow certain tags, you should use HTMLPurifier. Even `strip_tags` is not 100% safe.

Comment: With `str_tags()` you can specify allowable tags (second parameter). Build a list of tags to keep and strip all others!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip-tags) supports whitelisting certain tags, so you could use it to permit just the html tags you need. I would sanitise the whole string, though, as zerkms suggests, not enabling the users to write HTML code at all.

If you want to enable the users to markup their data, just use Markdown or a similar aproach.